# Meteor reset value of html input

Tags: html, meteor, coffeescript

I currently have an input box, which is inside a modal, setup like the following

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 8px">
  <label for="edit-user-email">Email Address</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="edit-user-email" value="{{getEmail}}">
</div>
```

And I have a UI helper to fill in the value setup below

```
UI.registerHelper "getEmail", () ->
  editUsersDep.depend()
  try
    #console.log Session.get("currentUser")
    return Session.get("currentUser").email.address
  catch e
    return
```

Now when I edit the value of the box, lets say changing the value from `test@gmail` to `test2@gmail` and then close my modal without actually updating the value for the `currentUser` session variable, and then re-open the modal I am expecting/wanting the value in that box to return to `test@gmail.com` but instead it is staying at `test2@gmail.com`.

The Session variable is being set as such. `this` corresponds to a row in a table. That works fine.

```
"click #foreman-edit-projects": () ->
    FlashMessages.clear()
    editUsersDep.changed()

    supersOfForeman = []
    projectsAdded = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this._id}).on_projects

    allSupers = Meteor.users.find({"roles.__global_roles__": {$in: ["admin", "super"]}, username: {$ne: "site.admin"}}).fetch()
    for admin in allSupers
      if admin.has_foreman
        if this._id in admin.has_foreman
          supersOfForeman.push(admin._id)
      else
        continue

    Session.set("editSupersForUser", supersOfForeman)
    Session.set("editProjectsForUser", this.on_projects)
    Session.set("currentUser", this)
    $("#editProjectsModal").modal("toggle")
```

The `console.log` I put in there to test that the method was actually being called when the modal pops up, which it does, but the value isn't changing. The `log` also always happens after I open the modal. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your question. I think you meant to say, *"...instead it is staying at **test2@gmail.com**"*.  If that's right, you might want to edit your question to reflect that.

Also, where are you setting the **Session** variable?

Comment: You are correct, my mistake there. I set the session variable when the modal containing the input box is opened.I have even tried to manually set the session variable at various times, but the only way the value changes is if I reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to get the current user's email address, you can use [`Meteor.user()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_user) rather than constantly trying to set your session variable.

So, you can replace it with:

```
UI.registerHelper "getEmail", () ->
  editUsersDep.depend()
  try
    return Meteor.user().emails[0].address
  catch e
    return
```